# Horizontal DIV image container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get my images to align horizontally but I seem to be doing something wrong but I have no clue what the problem is.

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ByDAA/4/

Here's the CSS:

```
.imgcontainer img {
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
padding:1px;
border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
margin:0px 37px 0px 0px;
width:175px;
height:175px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the container centered, or the images within the container..?

Comment: @JoshC Yes I want the container centered and I want the images to be horizontal to each other.

Comment: Why do you have `<br>` tags?

Comment: I removed them. I accidentally left them. @j08691

Comment: Images will be next to each other and at the bottom of each image you want to place "Let Us Sell It"?

Comment: @akinuri Yes that's correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap each `img` and `p` with a `div` and use `float:left`. Example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ByDAA/9/)

Comment: I made a bit of small changes to yours but now I can't get it aligned back into the middle. http://jsfiddle.net/ByDAA/17/

Comment: You want `.imgcontainer` to be centered? Like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ByDAA/18/)

Answer (score 0):

You're seeing line breaks because you explicitly put them there with `<br>` elements.

To achieve the intended effect, put the images and their subtexts in a separate container (`div` or `article`) and apply the `display:inline-block` style to *that* element.

Comment: Yes I did that earlier and it works but on a mobile device it doesn't display correctly because of the separate container.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
    float: left;
```

and change your css - remove unneded properties

Comment: Won't work as long as his HTML is screwed up with the sparse `br` and `p` elements between the images.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I removed br and p, now what?

Comment: put the float property to the imgcontainer CSS block

Comment: @yossico that doesn't work. Put in and you'll see what I'm seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Might this be what you are after? http://jsfiddle.net/taneleero/ByDAA/7/

Assuming that you would like the "Let Us Sell It" to align with each image I added containers around each image + the text and set them to inline-blocks. For the container I assigned text-align:center so the inline-blocks would align to the center. Also I changed to images do display:block to force the text below the image.

```
  .container {
      position: absolute;
      margin: auto;
      width: 100%;
      text-align:center;
  }
  .imgcontainer img {
      display:block;
      position:relative;
      padding:1px;
      border: 1px solid #c4c4c4;
      width:175px;
      height:175px;
  }
span {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0px 37px 0px 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap each image and text element in a specific element (a div or figure).

A figure is probably best as it allows the use of the `figcaption` element inside it for the text.

Each figure is set as `display:inline-block` and `vertical-align: top` and the container is set to `text-align:center`

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/7103050654936eab729233325edba0e9)